# Sum specific elements of a list

Tags: r, list

```
a<-list(5,6,8,4,5,2)
b<-c(3,2,1)
```

I want to sum the "a" according to "b" to form a new list.

that is (5+6+8),(4+5),2

The expected result is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 19

[[2]]
[1] 9

[[3]]
[1] 2
```

I use the following code to work out, but I wonder whether there is more convenient way to solve this problem. Thank you!

```
p<-rep(1:length(b),b)
as.list(sapply(1:length(b), function(x) {sum(as.numeric(a)[which(p==x)])}))
```

Comment: Your logic is pretty much all I can think of, though it could be shortened `tapply(unlist(a), rep(seq_along(b), b), sum)`

Comment: and another `rowsum(unlist(a), rep(b, b), reorder=FALSE)`

Comment: @user20650 I was thinking about your solution and realized that the grouping argument needs to be `rep(seq_along(b),b)` rather than `rep(b,b)`, otherwise duplicate values in `b` would be incorrectly aggregated into the same group. I applied the fix for the performance testing included in my answer and found it actually improves your solution's performance for some reason; now it's almost as fast as my solution :)

Comment: oh, you're quite right @bgoldst. Thanks for fixing / updating. (nice answer btw)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've thought of an interesting solution to this problem, which is perhaps a little strange, but I like it:

```
as.list(diff(c(0,cumsum(a)[cumsum(b)])));
## [[1]]
## [1] 19
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 9
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 2
##
```

### Explanation

---

First we take a complete cumulative sum with [`cumsum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html). Note: I originally thought `cumsum()` required an atomic vector (like [`sum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html), for example), and thus I initially had a call to `unlist()` prior to `cumsum()`, but thanks to @thelatemail for pointing out that it can work with lists as well!

```
cumsum(a);
## [1]  5 11 19 23 28 30
```

Then the *endpoints* of the ranges to be summed are extracted by indexing on `cumsum(b)`:

```
cumsum(b);
## [1] 3 5 6
cumsum(a)[cumsum(b)];
## [1] 19 28 30
```

We can produce the required summations by taking [`diff()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html) with a leading zero:

```
diff(c(0,cumsum(a)[cumsum(b)]));
## [1] 19  9  2
```

And since you want the result as a list, we finally need a call to [`as.list()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html):

```
as.list(diff(c(0,cumsum(a)[cumsum(b)])));
## [[1]]
## [1] 19
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 9
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 2
##
```

### Performance

---

```
lightsnail <- function() { p<-rep(1:length(b),b); as.list(sapply(1:length(b), function(x) {sum(as.numeric(a)[which(p==x)])})); };
thelatemail <- function() as.list(tapply(unlist(a), rep(seq_along(b), b), sum)); ## added as.list()
psidom <- function() lapply(split(unlist(a), rep(seq_along(b), b)), sum);
tfc <- function() as.list(aggregate(unlist(a), list(rep(1:length(b),b)), sum)[["x"]]);
user20650 <- function() as.list(rowsum(unlist(a), rep(seq_along(b), b), reorder=FALSE));
bgoldst <- function() as.list(diff(c(0,cumsum(a)[cumsum(b)])));

expected <- list(19,9,2);
identical(expected,lightsnail());
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,unname(thelatemail())); ## ignore names
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,unname(psidom())); ## ignore names
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,tfc());
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,user20650());
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,bgoldst());
## [1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark);
microbenchmark(lightsnail(),thelatemail(),psidom(),tfc(),user20650(),bgoldst(),times=1e3L);
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval
##   lightsnail()  26.088  33.358  37.34079  37.206  39.344  100.927  1000
##  thelatemail() 121.881 135.139 151.77782 142.837 150.963 3547.386  1000
##       psidom()  48.753  55.595  61.13800  59.016  63.507  276.693  1000
##          tfc() 574.767 613.256 646.64302 628.652 645.757 1923.586  1000
##    user20650()  17.534  23.094  25.49522  25.232  26.943  101.782  1000
##      bgoldst()  10.264  14.969  17.61914  17.535  18.817   82.965  1000
```

Comment: You can lose the `unlist` - `as.list(diff(c(0, cumsum(a)[cumsum(b)] )))` works too

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail! I didn't know `cumsum()` works on lists as well as atomic vectors. It's strange that `sum()` (and many other functions) don't work on lists, while `cumsum()` does.

Comment: Thanks @lightsnail :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option: `lapply(split(unlist(a), rep(seq_along(b), b)), sum)`

Comment: Helpful. !     Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no reason to use lists when you are actually working with vectors. Then another two approaches are as follows:

```
a <- c(5, 6, 8, 4, 5, 2)
b <- c(3, 2, 1)

f <- function(a, b) c(sum(head(a, b[1])), if(length(b) > 1) f(tail(a, -b[1]), b[-1]))
f(a, b)
# [1] 19  9  2

library(Matrix)
(a %*% bdiag(lapply(b, rep, x = 1)))[1, ]
# [1] 19  9  2
```

The first one is recursive, it keeps shortening `a` and `b` in every call, whereas the second approach constructs an auxiliary block diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is more convenient, but you can use aggregate with the index you created (p):

```
as.list(aggregate(unlist(a), list(rep(1:length(b),b)), sum)[["x"]])
```